# How would I go about developing a linker molecule that binds SiO2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, materials

I'm trying to develop a molecule that acts as a bridge between a protein and surface of SiO2 lattice. The end that binds the protein is simple and easy but I can't figure out a way to draft up how I can get the other end to bind SiO2.

So my question is, anyone have an idea on what particular molecule or reaction I can look at that targets Silicon molecules or has a high affinity for binding specifically SiO2? It doesn't even have to be a chemical bond that links the bridge to the SiO2, it could be an electrostatic/polar interaction too.

Thank you.

Comment: You should search silane chemistry. Molecules can be easily bound to silica using functionalized triethoxysilane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to bind an organic molecule to silicium oxide. It is necessary to synthesize the Si-O bond. It cannot be done starting from $\ce{SiO2}$. A possibility is to react $\ce{CH3Cl}$ over elementary silicium at high temperature to carry out the reaction :  $\ce{2 CH3Cl + Si > Si(CH3)2Cl2}$. Another approach is to make methyl sodium $\ce{NaCH3}$ react with gaseous $\ce{SiCl4}$ to produce : $\ce{SiCl4 + 3 NaCH3 -> Si(CH3)3Cl}$. These compounds can react with an alcool, like for example : $\ce{Si(CH3)3Cl + ROH -> Si(CH3)3OR + HCl}$. And here you obtain a molecule belonging to the class of the silicone. It contains the bond Si-O-C that you were looking for.

Comment: thank you friend, you knew exactly  what I was looking for!